# How to get selected checkbox id with comma separated which value is 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made this select all script for select check box.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#selecctall', function () {
    if (this.checked) { // Check select status
        $('.chkAssets').each(function () { // Loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = true; // Select all checkboxes with class "chkAssets"  
            $(this).attr('value', this.checked ? 1 : '')
        });
    } else {
        $('.chkAssets').each(function () { // Loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = false; // Deselect all checkboxes with class "chkAssets"
            $(this).attr('value', this.checked ? '' : '')
        });
    }
});
```

Now I want to get selected check box `id` with comma separated which value is `1`.

**Note: I want get result on button click event.**

**MY JSFiddle Work: http://jsfiddle.net/ybtreuhg/**

Comment: So, what's the purpose of setting the value to `1`? To indicate that the elements have been selected with the "Select all" checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("#getAll").click(function () {
    var id = $("[type=checkbox][value=1]:checked").map(function () {
        return this.id;
    }).get().join(",");

    alert(id);
});
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ybtreuhg/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

I updated in your code. [look this](http://jsfiddle.net/mob3mk5w/)

```
var selected = new Array();
$('input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '#selecctall', function () {
    $("input:checkbox").attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});

$("#getAll").click(function () {
    var ids = "";
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").not("#selecctall").each(function () {
        ids = ids + $(this).attr("id") + ",";
    })
    alert(ids);
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/ybtreuhg/7/)